# WebRTC RtpDataChannels Deprecated

Tags: webrtc

> 201 [Deprecation] RTP data channels are no longer supported. The "RtpDataChannels" constraint is currently ignored, and may cause an error at a later date.

But what is the migration path? I did a search and can only find info telling us to migrate to `SCTP`, without any details.

[Remove WebRTC RTP data channels (removed)](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6485681910054912)

I am thinking if we shall use the `WebSocket` channel (the one we used to establish the WebRTC Connection) to replace `RtpDataChnanels`.

Comment: it would be good to link to the source of that quote, as well as any info you found but wasn't sufficient

Comment: @underscore_d I have added the link

Comment: Opening a `RTCDataChannel` once you have a `RTCPeerConnection` is trivial. That's what they mean by migrate to SCTP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a peer-to-peer application: Use the standard WebRTC data channels; if in Javascript, just remove the constraint saying "I want to use RTP data channels", and most or all of your applications will work just like before, only better.

Why would anyone want to use that old relic?

Comment: WebRTC can stream Video, Video and Screen. But I wish to send data as well (like short text from chat message). May I know how can I do that? Standard WebRTC data channels means the WebSocket / Socket.io channels that we use to establish the WebRTC?

Comment: you can use data channels for that. You just should not use the "rtp" ones.

Comment: Standard WebRTC datachannels means the datachannels you get by calling "createDataChannel()" on an RTCPeerConnection, when you have *not* specified the special option to use RTP data channel when creating the peerconnection.

RTP != RTC.

Comment: Thanks, after removing the ``RtpDataChannels``, I need to handle the ``ondatachannel``, after that everything works automagically.